# How can I run msg.exe (or an alternative) from a java application on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: java, windows-7

The following line works fine from my java application on Windows XP:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("msg.exe * this is a test");
```

When it executes on Windows 7 (64-bit), I get the following error:

Cannot run program "msg.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I have tried putting in the full path to the .exe, and I get the same error:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\Windows\\System32\\msg.exe * this is a test");
```

Using ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime gives the same error:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("msg.exe * this is a test").start();
```

I tried to rule out a permissions issue by temporarily giving everyone full control to msg.exe but Windows would not let me - the options were greyed out even when I logged in as administrator.

So I confirmed that the user of the java process has read and execute permissions to msg.exe.

I am able to successfully run the command (as the same user of the java process) from the command line of the Windows 7 machine.

In the notes of this post: [C# cannot find file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680045/c-sharp-cannot-find-file-specified), someone alludes to a similar issue with a Windows 64-bit machine not finding msg.exe from a C# program, so perhaps there is something on the Windows configuration side that I need to do?

Is there a way to get a java application to send a network message on Windows 7?  Or some alternative for sending a network message that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a 32-bit Java installation, which wouldn't be allowed to start 64-bit programs on Windows 7. If you have 32-bit Java installed, upgrade to 64-bit Java and then try again.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment (especially since the acceptance indicates that this was, in fact, the questioner's actual problem?)

Comment: To confirm: that was absolutely the problem.  Running it with the 64-bit jre did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please try: `new ProcessBuilder("msg.exe", "* test").start()`